# Chat application using grpc streaming

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, microservices, grpc, google-cloud-run

I am building an one to one chat application using grpc streaming(go).
I was able to achieve it by maintaining map of active users connections.
I am planning to deploy in cloud run or web app.

**Problem** :
If I set the minimum nodes as 2 for deployment. One container is not aware of other containers active users connections map. That breaks the application.

Is there a way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to move your app's shared state (`map`) to a service where it can be shared across an arbitrary number of Cloud Run instances.

A common way to implement this is to use a (shared) cache e.g. [Cloud Memorystore](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore).

Adding such a service introduces complexity and cost so please ensure you understand the consequences before you proceed.

Comment: I tried to store map states in redis. But couldn't able to use those stored states in other micro services since it stored as strings. Can you please share any relevant links/code samples which stores the client state in redis and use it in other micro services. I tried very hard to solve this problem, but no success

Comment: You'll need to work out for yourself a way to marshal|serialize your connection datatypes into e.g. Redis (datatypes) and back. Good luck!